# Python iterators and Pandas groupby : set starting point

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, iterator, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe. I have grouped them based on a certain column.
The dataframe shape is `(1275553, 87)`

I have then created an iterator, which lets me iterate through each group in order to create an animation.
I would like to be able to specify the starting point for the iterator, as I would using `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group`. Currently, I'm forced to iterate through the various groups until I have reached my desired starting point, which doesn't seem very efficient:

```
counter_group = df.groupby('counterValue')
temp=iter(counter_group)
while count != 20302:
   count, frame = next(temp)
#do something with frame
```

I was playing around with `iterator.send()` though I can't figure out how to use it in GroupBy.
I would much appreciate any help. If the question requires some sample input, I shall update if requested.

I'm using python 3.7.7, and pandas 1.0.4

Comment: you can fetch the group names by `groups` to a list `lst` and then access by group name in a loop starting in `lst[20302:]`

Comment: @LiorCohen are you suggesting I create a generator and each time feed a new key to `get_group` from the `lst` ?

Comment: not a generator just `list(temp.groups.keys())[20302:]`

Comment: @LiorCohen thank you for your suggestion. I used your idea to create a separate generator, but it was from your idea nevertheless.